# Linux router can communicate with peer's own AS, but not any provided routes

Tags: networking, routing, bgp

I have recently set up my first non-provider BGP peer on an exchange-connected linux router, but I am having an odd problem with traffic flow. On my paid transit provider, I can reach all addresses without problems. With the peer however, I can reach all networks on the peer's own AS, but cannot reach any of the other routes shared over BGP. The routes are successfully shared over the BGP session, and accepted into the FIB, but pings and trace routes show no output or returned packets. I cannot think of what might be causing this, and would typically think that this would indicate a problem with the peer's network, but considering that I am relatively new at network engineering, I would like to make sure that my setup is absolutely airtight before contacting support. I am running BIRD 2.13 and Ubuntu 20.04. I have disabled RPF for the interface in question. Do you have any ideas of what else might be causing these issues?

Comment: Do you see packets being sent out to the correct gateway's MAC in a packet capture? Do your _other_ interfaces have RPF disabled as well? Which path is taken if you do a "reverse" traceroute from some target back to your address?